# During RMAN backup, shutdown immediate database and facing error ORA-12514: TNS:listener?

Tags: oracle

I was taking an RMAN backup.

```
 RMAN>  SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
```

After Shutdown Immediate i am not able to startup database.
I have tried

1. conn sys@databasename as sysdba
2. RMAN target sys@database
3. lsnrctl stop start status

But i am getting this error.

```
C:\Users\Umair>rman target sys@ora_prep

Recovery Manager: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Mon Jul 13 00:18:00 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

target database Password:
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00554: initialization of internal recovery manager package failed
RMAN-04005: error from target database:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Advice, please.Thank you.

Oracle 12.1.0
Windows 10

Comment: Of course if you shut down your database and your listener.ora file does not have the necessary SID_LIST entries, then rman (or anything else) is not going to be able to establish a tns connection to an idle instance.  I would not be doing any of this through a tns connection, but rather run the rman from the db server so as to use an IPC connection.  And why shut down the database at all?

Comment: Thank you for reply.I shut down the database before backup as per instruction guide. So what would be the way to startup?

Comment: is the database installed as windows-service? then the service-manager could be used to bring up the instance again

Comment: Michael All the oracle services are already running on the windows server.

Comment: "shut down the database before backup as per instruction guide."  What/whose instruction guide?  I never shut down my databases for a backup.  If your databases are in archivelog mode they can and should be backed up while fully open and operational.  If they are not in archivelog mode .... well, then you must not consider the database to be valuable, because you will NEVER be able to fully recover it.  The way to startup is to open a command session _on the db server_, set ORACLE_SID, connect with sqlplus 'sqlplus / as sysdba', and issue a 'startup' command. Very elementary.

Answer (score 0):

Static listener registration:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spmss/adding-static-service-to-listener.html
- https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2312510_1.html